# mvn package or mvn install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm a new developer, never worked with eclipse or java at all in my life, and I'm trying to do something but I'm really clue less. I downloaded a project from github, and in the installation guide it says:

> Once you have the sources, run mvn package or mvn install to create 2
>   jars - hebmorph-core and hebmorph-lucene. Those 2 packages are
>   required before moving on to the next step.

its probably a dumb question, but I cant figure out how to get those jar files. I got lost in the eclipse environment and after few hours of research could found a suitable answer.

there is a direct link to the [pom.xml](https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph/blob/master/java/pom.xml) file from git.

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

When you execute `mvn package` or `mvn install`, the generated jars are placed in the `target` folder. The difference between the two commands is that with `mvn install` the generated jars are also installed in the local Maven repository, placed by default in the `.m2/repository` directory inside the user home.

Answer (score 3):

Just execute from your main project folder:

> mvn package

or

> mvn install

`package` and `install` are Maven phases.

***package*** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.

***install*** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally

For more info just follow [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1):

mvn package puts the jar in target dir of project.
mvn install also copies it (after packaging) to your local mvn repository which is defined in your settings.xml file